# как изменить стрелки слайдера посредством Бутстрапа от твитера

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, carousel

Необходимо на бутстрапе исправить и сделать стрелки пролистывания слайдов как на картинке 2(полукруг). могу на сss это сделать, но стрелки теряют адаптивность и приходится вручную адаптировать под размер экрана их - это не удовлетворяет требованиям, необходимо использовать максимально возможности Бутстрапа, подскажите пожалуйста можно ли организовать это на бутстрапе и как определить ,что бутстрап сам с этим не справится и необходимо использовать уже чисто css. Less не желательно применять...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Учитесь верстать без бутстрапа и не занимайтесь онанизмом

Comment: собственно совета по тому что использовать я не спрашивал, а задал конкретный вопрос...